# Including TTS voices in TTS supporting software

Tags: sapi, text-to-speech

Let's say that I want to add TTS support to my project, and that I hate the voice of Microsoft Sam, Microsoft Mike and Microsoft Mary.
Would it be possible for me to include a new TTS voice that I bought into my software, so that the TTS support could be limited to the voices I included, instead of the software picking voices from the computer it runs on?

If so, what engine / sdk should I use for this?
I have been searching for answers on google, but I can only find ways to use SAPI with voices from the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAPI Voices that are paid are usually licensed to the owner of the computer.  You might be able to include free TTS voices from the Festival Engine.